# Intel IPP library requirements

Tags: hyperthreading, intel-ipp

So I am trying to compile an Intel IPP sample application that comes with the library -- string matching --, and I don't seem be able to leverage the IPP instructions. The computational time stays the same when I disable one of the cores on my machine. I would like to know if my machine meets all the requirements for the IPP, and/or why this situation exists.

Here is the environment:

- Windows 7
- IPP 7.0
- Intel Core i3 (2 cores with 2 threads for each)
- I disable cores using the msconfig option (Boot tab > advanced options...)

I am assuming that Hyperthreading is supported/enabled on my machine, since as you can see in the picture [image]
number of logical processors are larger than the number of processors.

Comment: IPP uses all available computer resources, performance with multicore support must be better. How exactly you enable/disable miltiple processors, and measure execution time?

Comment: @AlexFarber, to enable/disable multiple processors, I use msconfig, and on the Boot menu, select the advanced options, and then select the number of processors from the drop-down menu. I set it on 4 for full computational power, and 1 for partial. For execution time, I use the clock_t data type from the time.h header file.

Answer (score 0):

did you use the intel icc compiler provided? The performance is better using intel compiler and ipp together.

Comment: I am using Intel Parallel Studio - It's totally baffling me as the result I get from 1 logical processor is slightly better than one I get with 4 processors.